# How can I prevent the Facebook session key from expiring

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, facebook

I am developing a Facebook app in Zend Framework. I am using the Facebook session key for my PHP session ID (this is the practice recommended by Facebook). The problem is that after an hour or so, it appears that the Facebook session key expires because I lose my PHP session. Is there a way to prevent (or at least significantly delay) the expiration of the Facebook session key? Thanks!

Comment: Is this a Facebook app or a Facebook Connect app?

Comment: It is a Facebook app, although I'm not sure what Facebook Connect gives me that I can't get through the Facebook API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your core problem is that php invalids your php session (that can be easily fixed in framework)

or

your problem is that facebook does no longer accept your api requests on behalf of the user become it timeouted

one hour sounds by far to long for facebook api calls if there are no canvas calls in between

see the [wiki](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions) and search for offline_access

Comment: Thanks. I needed offline_access from extended permissions. It works perfectly now.

Comment: Chris, this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500) might also help you with figuring out how to handle expired access tokens. (Hey Andreas, nice running into you on here.)